# SQL or Code: difference between table snapshot and current table; which is more efficient?

Tags: sql, delphi

I need to take a snapshot of a table at a given time, and determine the difference between the snapshot and the current data. What is the most effective way to do that? Can it be done in pure SQL (MS SQL), or do my app server do that in Delphi code?

I'm using an app server that keeps track of these changes, and transmit them over a Telnet protocol to any number of clients/ on the same machine or not.

Because of the txt protocol, I have to use the difference of the tables because it is impractical to send all the data (~10k records) every time something changes.

The apps involved are, Swordfish (an Automatic Trading System/ ATS), not written by me. The app server (Chef), and the client (Diner), both written by me. The ATS uses MS SQL as a layer for its API, so Chef, sends and receives data to the MS SQL server, essentially controlling the ATS. The client communicates what it wants done to Chef, and then Chef talks to Swordfish through the DBMS, and the the other Diners, through Telnet.

Comment: at the moment I am notified about a change in the SQL query through a service broker event

Comment: Which database are you using? What do you mean by "sending ~10k records every time something changes"? Does your app keep the 10,000 records in memory? Note that Delphi normally fetches the current record before editing.

Comment: a) Is the other app running on the same machine as your app; b) are they the only apps making changes to the database and c) is the other app one you have written?

Comment: This is normally done with an app server that runs close to the db. All updates go via the app server. Do not write directly to the db. This way the all server knows about every change and can feed them to other clients.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing, I have the app server and I have any amount of clients connecting to the app server. There is a ATS (automatic trading system) Swordfish, that writes and reads API commands through a MS SQL database. My server watches the changes made by Swordfish and keeps an in memory copy of the data, to compare with the new set (~10k) of records (that's just the last price table). SO, because it is kinda heavy to keep that many records as duplicates in memory, I wondered if it could be done in SQL. SO the server sends info about these changes to any number of clients.

Comment: The clients connect through the Telnet protocol, so it can be on the same machine or not. The reason why I chose telnet, right or wrong. is on the client side, I can react through an event initiated by the server, because the server knows when a new record arrives and I didn't want the client to poll the server for that data, however, I assumed the telnet component does polling behind the scenes, but then I didn't have to, I get it event driven...

Comment: maybe like adding the current table under an alias to the MS SQL database and then using a SQL query to determine the difference between the new dataset and the saved dataset (both in the MS SQL server)

Comment: You need to restate/edit your question so it actually clear what setup you're using. If there **is** a middle layer normally you'd use or create event handlers in that middle layer that you can hook into to keep you updated on what's happening.

Comment: If you want to know about changes to a specific table in a database, then a trigger on that table can do that for you. I don't have a clear enough picture to know if triggers can help you though.

Comment: as far as my research goes (please advise if I'm wrong), a trigger only notifies me that the (service broker) query/that essentially becomes an event, have changed, not the actual records that have changed. I am using such events to know that I have a new dataset ready, but the difference is still up to me to determine, the question then becomes, what is the most efficient way to calculate the difference between the snapshot (previous event) and current data (this event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code. Is the most  efficient way to do this. *According to all the info that I could find on the web*

It may be possible to know with pure SQL what rows were added, but I could find nothing (in SQL) to detect changes to already existent rows or row deletes, both of which I need knowledge of to keep my app server (that is aware and synced with the SQL table) and my app clients synchronized.

Keeping an in-memory table of 10-15k records isn't that serious, a different error in my code (to do with TFDQuery) made me think that my "offline" or "in memory" snapshot op the tables needed A LOT of memory (every sql add command created it's own instance of TFDQuery, requiring 30mb per record that leaked when destroying the TFDQuery, now I create the instance of TFDQuery once, and reuse the instance for every record added, and my memory usage total stays ~50mb, which I have no problem with)

So, every time Service Broker detects a change in the dataset of the sql table, I save the old dataset to a in-memory table, and do 3 compares between dataset and dataset (dataset saved/old and dataset current/the newest version of the SQL table). 1. Scan for addition. 2. Scan for changes. 3 Scan for deletion, DONE :-)

Then its' a simple task of encoding the text for the Telnet protocol, and all my clients and my SQL server and my app server are happily synced!